# how to proceed in the following Question

Tags: conic-sections, locus

**Question**

What is the Locus of the foot of the perpendicular drawn from the centre of the ellipse $x^2$ +$3y^2$ = 6

I proceeded by assuming a pt $(h,k)$ as the foot of the perpendicular to the tangent drawn and found the slope of the tangent through differentiating the equation of ellipse
at that point I then put the values in the point slope form but then realised that I could not eliminate the parameter that is why I am confused on how to proceed thanks in advance please answer asap and tell me if I am doing some trivial mistake .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th equation of the tangent  at $(\sqrt6\cos t,\sqrt2\sin t)$:

$$\sqrt6\cos t\cdot\dfrac x6+\sqrt2\sin t\cdot\dfrac y2=1$$

So, the equation of the perpendicular through the  center $(0,0)$ of the ellipse will be

$$\sqrt2\sin t\cdot\dfrac x2-\sqrt6\cos t\cdot\dfrac y6=0$$

Now solve for $x,y$ to find the coordinate of the foot.

Find $\dfrac xy,$  replace this value of $\tan t$ in

$$x=\cdots$$ which is a function of $\cos t,\sin t$

Comment: how did u take the points icannot understand that  is it by the normal form of the line

Comment: @PrateekChauhan, See http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa09/Yun/jyun_assign10/Parametric_eq_yun.html

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee thanks understood wht u hv done and why , u are a real life saver thanks a ton